# casperjs can't find the id after set id

Tags: javascript, browser, phantomjs, casperjs

casperjs can't find the id after set id

```
casper.then(function () {
screenLog();
var id =  String("_newid_");
var arrow = this.evaluate(function () {
    var arrows = document.querySelectorAll('span.select2-selection__arrow');
    arrows[1].innerHTML = "aa";
    arrows[1].id = id;
    return arrows[1].innerHTML;
});
screenLog();
this.click("#"+id);
screenLog();});
```

and then error code :
 CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: #*newid*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caspers evaluate method runs in separate environment(DOM environment) so the variables defined in casper environment are not accessible in browser environment. However you can pass the variable to browser environment by adding extra parameters to evaluate function.

So for your case id is undefined, but you can pass it properly like this

```
var id =  String("_newid_");
var arrow = this.evaluate(function (id) {
    var arrows = document.querySelectorAll('span.select2-selection__arrow');
    arrows[1].innerHTML = "aa";
    arrows[1].id = id;
    return arrows[1].innerHTML;
}, id);
```